# Verification to my answers for a combinatoric problem.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A computer programming team has 13 members.

i) Suppose two team members refuse to work together on projects. How many groups of seven can be chosen to work on a project?

My answer being: $\binom{11}{7} + 2 \binom{11}{6}$

ii) Suppose two team members insist on either working together or not at all on projects. How many groups of seven can be chosen to work on a project?

My answer being: $\binom{11}{5} + \binom{11}{7}$

I originally thought I was correct, but the solutions manual says $\binom{11}{7} + 2\binom{12}{7}$ for i, and $\binom{12}{6} + \binom{11}{7}$ for ii. I adamantly think the solutions manual is wrong here, but now I have doubts in my own answers now.

Comment: The manual is wrong.  Your answers are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are correct. For part i, ignore the two arguing programmers. There are $\binom{11}{7}$ ways to select a team without them. Then there are $2 \binom{11}{6}$ ways to select a team of seven including precisely one of the two arguing programmers. This would mean your answer of $\binom{11}{7} + 2 \binom{11}{6}$ is correct, not the solutions manual's.

Similarly for part ii, there are $\binom{11}{7}$ ways to select a team without them, and $\binom{11}{5}$ ways including them. So your answer of $\binom{11}{7} + \binom{11}{5}$ is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to answer (i) which agrees with your answer:

From all possible combinations $_{13}C_7$ subtract those combinations with the two hostile programmers $_{11}C_5$.

Another way to answer (ii) which agrees with your answer:

From all possible combinations $_{13}C_7$ subtract those combinations with exactly one of the two "all-or-nothing" programmers $2 \cdot _{11}C_6$.